Constant current opto input circuit
I have implemented the below circuit in a small project I'm working on which is based on a suggestion in another post, Optocoupler circuit accept input between 3-50 volt
It all works fine with a normal 5V pulse for example, however what I've found is that when a water flow meter is connected (FS300A) with a 5V supply, the output pulse is only about 1.2V whereas the OC value is around 4.5V so is being dragged down at some point.
I'm using the following components for reference and currently using the following fluid sensor.
https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/g3_4_water_flow_sensor_-_wiki.pdf
Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.


How do you have the sensor hooked up? Put it on the schematic as that's the most  prominent part.

pspeirs, Since you are working with an npn open collector output, you'd be better off using a high side current source using pnp transistors. Just flip over the design.

@periblepsis, the input circuit has no ground reference. It can work as a source (PULSE_IN1 connected to +5 V) or a sink (other terminal connected to 5V GND).

@Transistor I was making assumptions when I wrote. (Didn't have much choice about it.)

It seems that the sensor has an open-collector output, requiring a single resistance to +5V, which is well illustrated in the document you linked to. That document, by the way, shows a breadboarded circuit which is incorrectly wired, and would not work.
Because of sensor's open-collector output, that signal is unable to maintain +5V under any modest load to ground, including the insightful constant-current limiter circuit provided in the other answer.
However, the documentation claims that the sensor is able to sink 10mA, which is easily adequate to drive the LED in the opto-coupler, and your circuit could be as simple as this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The 560Ω resistor sets LED current to about 6mA, which should be a good value for most models of opto-coupler, but is only valid if the flow sensor is powered with 5V. If you want to power it with a higher voltage (up to 24V according to the document) then you must increase R1 accordingly.
Theoretically, you could put the current-limiter circuit from the previous answer in the place of R1 here (observing polarity of course), and then the flow sensor can be powered from anything between 5V and 24V without damaging the opto-coupler.
Don't omit C1. It doesn't look important, but it is, and it should be installed as close as possible to the sensor's power supply connectors.

To implement the current limiter while retaining compatibility with the open-collector output, it can replace R1 above:

simulate this circuit
Current isn't truly constant over the entire supply range, but goes from a little over 5mA to about 9mA, as the supply goes from +5V to +50V. Of course the flow-meter won't tolerate over 24V.

The previous post wasn't asked by myself however seemed to fit my use case.  The input is not only designed for a 5V pulse meter otherwise yes, a simple resistor would have done the job.  It is designed for a pulse anywhere up to 30V or so which is why I went the constant current route.

@pspeirs I'm sorry, I didn't notice that, and I didn't notice the date on that other post. My Apologies.

@pspeirs I have included the current limiter, so things work at 30V (or 5V).

Initially, I suspected that whatever device you are connected across inputs "PULSE_IN1" and "PULSE_IN2" simply cannot deliver the ~6mA that the LED is asking for (via the constant-current configuration of Q5 & Q3).  However, the datasheet does suggest it can handle this amount of load (10mA @ 5VDC).

A simple test would confirm the unit is meeting specifications.  Disconnect this LED board, and place just a resistor across the output of the flow-meter; use a value of about 1kΩ, this should put a load of about 5mA on the output of the flow meter.  What does the voltage measure for each case of the output, ie: pulse ON and pulse OFF?  Next increase the load to about 10mA, by putting a resistor of about 470Ω.  What does the output voltage do now?
If all this tests OK, then the other things to look for are:

Is the flow-meter receiving a good reliable 5V at all times on its supply pins (Red and black wires).  Make sure the output signal is not causing this supply voltage to sag or dip.
Reduce the current in the opto LED (increase R39).  Do you really need 5 or 6mA?


Using a 1k resistor the pulse is around 400mV, 4k7 (close to 1mA) gives me around 1.5V. It would suggest these sensors are really not up to spec.

Comment 1: The pulse terminals on your circuit should be "PULSE_IN1+" and "PULSE_IN1-". The OUT reference reads as though you've got a pulse generator rather than a pulse detector.
I was unable to find a datasheet for the flow sensor that gave a proper internal diagram.
Makers Electronics says that the maximum load capacity is ≤ 10 mA.
Q3 and Q5 on your circuit form a constant current circuit with current determined by R39 and the base-emitter forward voltage, Vf of Q3. \$ I_{CC} = \frac {V_f} R = \frac {0.7} {100} = 7\ \text{mA} \$ which should be OK for the sensor.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Most likely connection circuit.

I think rather stupidly I had the output connected to PULSE_IN+ and Negative into PULSE_IN-.  Once configured as above, I was getting around 4.65V on the pulse.
